# Hosting angular application with proxy configuration

Tags: angular, nginx, configuration

I am building a dictionary application using angular which uses oxford dictionary API to retrieve the data . In the development environment I have used proxy.conf.json to forward the requests.This is my proxy.conf.json file

```
{
"/oxfordapi": {
  "target": "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/",
  "secure": true,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "app_id": "cb35ef20",
    "app_key": "603be016c344650e6d8c1da15330f7af"
  },
  "pathRewrite": {"^/oxfordapi" : ""}
 }
}
```

When I build the application for the production version and host it on my nginx server it always gives error when i try to  get data from the server.
I have read proxy_pass in nginx server config can be used but I am newbie to nginx server please help me fix this problem. If possible give the full server configuration for this issue  .Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your current NGINX configuration?

Comment: `server{
 root /home/ubuntu/test/dist/demo;
 index index.html;
 server_name test.vivekm.me;
  location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:-

```
server {

      root /home/ubuntu/test/dist/demo; 
      index index.html; 
      server_name test.vivekm.me; 

      location /oxfordapi {
        proxy_pass https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/;
        proxy_set_header Accept application/json;
        proxy_set_header app_id $http_app_id;
        proxy_set_header app_key $http_app_key;
      }

      location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I need to send the headers also  `"headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "app_id": "cb35ef20",
    "app_key": "603be016c344650e6d8c1da15330f7af"
  }`

Comment: Please try the updated answer and let me know the results. Thanks

Comment: Still I get the error as authentication parameters are missing

Comment: Are the `app_id` and `app_key` sent from the front end?

Comment: No they are set in proxy.conf.json

Comment: Where does this file reside... at the back end?

Comment: No the file is only present in the development environment. Production version does not contain that file.

Comment: Ok, try hard coding the values for now and see if it works... `proxy_set_header app_id cb35ef20;`. Do for both the headers...

Comment: No now it produces the 404 error . I will  try to change the service to send the headers with the request itself and will update the result.Here is my app repo [https://bitbucket.org/vivek1996/oxforddemo/src/master/] (https://bitbucket.org/vivek1996/oxforddemo/src/master/)

Comment: Pls check the logs to figure out the URL that NGINX is building. It must be appending the URL that you are trying to hit from the front end which does not exist there.

Comment: Even i changed the service to send the headers with the request the **Authentication parameters missing** error is produced but the request headers contains the app_id and app_key. How can I use the change origin and path rewrite in the nginx conf

Comment: Dont use these proxy_set_header app_id $http_app_id; proxy_set_header app_key $http_app_key; and it will work fine.