# angular proxy for external api during deployment

Tags: angular, nginx, proxy

I am building a dictionary application using angular which uses oxford dictionary API to retrieve the data.But oxford dictionaries API currently does not support CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).
Instead they recommend to make the query reach user's server side application, and then send the API request from the user's server to oxford's server rather than directly from the client.So it's not possible to directly send API requests to their server.

In the development environment I have used proxy.conf.json to forward the requests.For hosting it on an nginx server I tried this question's solution [Hosting angular application with proxy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373171/hosting-angular-application-with-proxy-configuration)  but it returns 404 data not found.

Here's the congifuration default file

```
server {

        server_name adityafrontend.co.in;
        root /home/ubuntu/angular-dictionary;

         location /api {

             proxy_pass https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/;
             proxy_set_header Accept application/json;
             proxy_set_header app_id 6*****;
             proxy_set_header app_key 6****************;
         }


        location /{

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            #Allows page refresh in angular app
        }


}
```

[header information in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqUJP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but changing /api to /api/ worked for me.